# Generating Google Docs from Google Sheets using Google Apps Script - "Too many changes applied before saving document" error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm currently using Google Apps Script to generate Google Docs from a Google Sheet. The data from the Google Sheet is used to populate the generated Google Doc.

When I add a few rows to the Google Sheet, the Google Doc is generated successfully. However, when I try to add multiple rows to the sheet, I encounter the following error:

```
Too many changes applied before saving document. Please save changes in smaller batches using Document.saveAndClose(), then reopen the document with Document.openById().
```

I followed the advice from the error message and tried to save changes in smaller batches using Document.saveAndClose(), and then reopen the document with Document.openById(). However, I encountered a new error

```
Exception: Document is closed, its contents cannot be updated.
```

Below is a simplified version of the code I'm using:

```
// Define the search parameters.
const searchHeading = DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1;
searchType = DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH;
let searchResult2 = null;
let i = 0;

// Find the "Test 1" header to detect where Test cases should start
while (true) {
  Logger.log(i);
  i++;
  if (i % 30 === 0) {
    docItem.saveAndClose();
    docItem = DocumentApp.openById(targetFile.getId());
    docBody = docItem.getBody();
  }

  searchResult2 = docBody.findElement(searchType, searchResult2);
  if (!searchResult2) break;

  // Get the element
  let par = searchResult2.getElement().asParagraph();

  // Check for heading type
  if (par.getHeading() == searchHeading) {

    // Check for heading text
    if (par.getText().trim() == 'TRIVE ES') {
      // Here is the right test case block

      // Elements to delete after getting the template
      let elementsToDelete = [par];

      // Let's find the block with the test case and save it like a template
      let testCaseTemplate = null;
      while (par = par.getNextSibling()) {

        // Get the element text to determine if it is the right block
        let text = par.asText().getText();
        if (text.indexOf('Actors:') != -1 && testCaseTemplate == null) {
          // Test block found, save it for future use
          testCaseTemplate = par.copy();
        }

        // Push this element to be deleted
        elementsToDelete.push(par);
      }

      // Keep the last paragraph
      elementsToDelete.pop();

      // Delete all elements
      for (let elementToDelete of elementsToDelete) {
        elementToDelete.removeFromParent();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I can successfully use saveAndClose, and then open the document in other parts of the code with no issues. However, I'm not sure why this issue is occurring in this specific section of the code.

Can someone help me pinpoint where the error is and suggest an alternative approach to saving the Google Doc? I've tried adding sleep commands, but they didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between Google Spreadsheet, Google Document, and your current issue in your showing script. Can I ask you about the details of them? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: You code is not reproducible so we cannot generate the problem thus it will be difficult for use to assist you.  Please provide and [mcve].  This example may not be the same as your code it is simply a piece of code that allows us to generate the problem so that we can assist you in finding the problem.